# What is difference between I am little confuse in difference Collection and Collections?

Tags: java, collections

What is difference between collection and collections ?

Could any one answer me .

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is clear on this one.

[Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is a collection of static methods, that operate or return an object of type `Collection`.

[Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)  represents a group of objects, known as its elements. It is an interface type that is implemented by anything that contains multiple objects.

Comment: "that operate or return an object of type Collection" It'd be nice if it were that cut and dry but what about `Collections.singletonList`, for example?

Comment: @Michael sure, but it also returns Set, List, Queue, .. but all have Collection has superinterface

Comment: maybe another view; `Collection` is an Interface for Classes holding several objcects; `Collections` is a collection of (static) Functions to operate on them. The concept is comparable to `Arrays`